# How to add help file to frame?

Tags: java, swing, file, mouseevent, frame

I'm making plugin for eclipse which opens frame with some table's when plugin command is activated. Now I want to add help file to plugin's frame, so that when clicked on help file's link in frame, file opens (executes). File is suppose to be part of plugin. My problems are:

1. Don't know how to make link and add it to frame.
2. Don't know how to locate that file in plugin from run time application.

   ```
   JLabel lblFileLink = new JLabel("Help");
   lblFileLink.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

   lblFileLink.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
           @Override
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
               try {
                   /* Add code for opening file from plugin.*/
               } catch (IOException e1) {

                   e1.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       });
   ```

Found this code somewhere, now I need to implement link, any thoughts?

Comment: Please specify, what do you mean with "file opens" ?

Comment: executes, open for example txt file.

Comment: open in what ? your own editor ?

Comment: In notepad, like readme.txt or in Eclipse editor, forgot to add this is eclipse plugin, sorry. I'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you question correct, something like this should work:

```
JLabel lblFileLink = new JLabel("Help");
lblFileLink.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

lblFileLink.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            try {
                java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().edit(INSERTYOURFILEHERE);
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

This will open the standard text editor and show your file. Just replace `INSERTYOURFILEHERE` with your own text file.

Edit: If you want to open it in Eclipse maybe look at [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_programmatically%3F)

Edit2: The gist of the link above:

```
File fileToOpen = new File("externalfile.xml");

if (fileToOpen.exists() && fileToOpen.isFile()) {
    IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(fileToOpen.toURI());
    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

    try {
        IDE.openEditorOnFileStore( page, fileStore );
    } catch ( PartInitException e ) {
        //Put your exception handler here if you wish to
    }
} else {
    //Do something if the file does not exist
}
```

Comment: where is this file suppose to be located? I need to open file that is part of plugin. What I mean is that this file needs to be located in plugin's package

Comment: can't open link you posted for to open it in eclipse

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_programmatically%3F doesnt work ?

Comment: yeah it is trying to connect but doesn't open, must be something with my network

Comment: @squlerr `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(YOURFILE);` should work for loading your file

Comment: I understand now what you did, still can't open my file, don't know how to locate it in plugin's folder

Comment: found this getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath(). It gives me plugin's folder finally

Comment: There is new problem, I got file with this IFileStore you proposed, but now I can't get active page, it is null. I assume it is because my frame is active at that moment, so he cant open editor, with IDE.open.... do you know how can I activate editors page??